# Compare two database table

Tags: mysql

I have two database tables, tmp1 and tmp2

tmp1:

```
+----+------+---------+---------+
| id | name | add1    | add2    |
+----+------+---------+---------+
| 1  | NULL | NULL    | NULL    |
| 2  | NULL | NULL    | NULL    |
| 3  | mum1 | rajpur1 | rajpur2 |
| 4  | mum3 | rajpur3 | rajpur4 |
| 5  | mum4 | rajpur4 | rajpur5 |
+----+------+---------+---------+
```

tmp2:

```
+----+------+---------+---------+
| id | name | add1    | add2    |
+----+------+---------+---------+
| 1  | NULL | NULL    | NULL    |
| 2  | mum  | rajpur  | rajpur1 |
| 3  | NULL | NULL    | NULL    |
| 4  | mum2 | rajpur2 | rajpur3 |
| 5  | mum4 | rajpur4 | rajpur5 |
+----+------+---------+---------+


select a.id 
from tmp1 a 
inner join tmp2 b 
where a.id = b.id 
  and (a.name is NULL or a.add1 is NULL or a.add2 is NULL) 
   or (a.name!=b.name or a.add1!=b.add1 or a.add2!=b.add2);
```

Here I have tried the above code to show the following result:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 3  |
| 4  | 
+----+
```

But it doesn't show me the desired result.

Here i want to print the first table's id where one or many other row's values are either null or one or many other row's values are unmatched with tmp2's those rows values.

Comment: Can you also paste the result you're getting?

Comment: +----+
| id |
+----+
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 3  |
| 4  |
| 5  |
| 3  |
| 4  |
| 5  |
| 3  |
| 4  |
+----+

Comment: Can there be a scenario, where only one column is null for a record in any table?

Comment: yes, there can be only one column that can hold a null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing the `ON`. And as The Impaler astutely pointed out, the columns in the temp2 also need to be checked for `NULL`.

```
select a.id 
from tmp1 a 
inner join tmp2 b on a.id=b.id
where coalesce(a.name,a.add1,a.add2,b.name,b.add1,b.add2) is null or
      coalesce(a.name,a.add1,a.add2)<>coalesce(b.name,b.add1,b.add2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `ON` clause that specifies how to join the table(s). Also, your search condition is incomplete.

```
select a.id
from tmp1 a
join tmp1 b on a.id = b.id
where a.name is null or a.add1 is null or a.add2 is null
   or b.name is null or b.add1 is null or b.add2 is null
   or (a.name <> b.name or a.add1 <> b.add1 or a.add2 <> b.add2)
```